# How to show that a function defines a tempered distribution and compute the Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

Consider the following functions : $f(x) = 1 + x \cos(3x)$ and $g(x) = x \sin^2(x)$. How can I show that $f$ and $g$ define tempered distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ and compute their Fourier transforms (in the sense of tempered distributions)? Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What textbook are you using ?

Comment: They don't grow faster than a polynomial and are therefore tempered distributions.

Comment: To find the transform of $x$, find the transform of $\delta'(x)$. $\sin$ and $\cos$ are just a multiplication by a complex exponential.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments.